# Solve[] cannot solve an expression but solves an identity expression

Tags: equation-solving

I am surprised that `Solve` cannot find analytical roots for an expression, but it finds roots for an identical expression.

How to reproduce:

```
Solve[-(-b^(2/3) + g^4) (b^(2/3) - 9 g^4 + 16 b^(2/3) g^6 - 9 b^(4/3) g^8 + b^(2/3) g^12) == 0, g]
```

No analytical solutions (it is kind of expected for a polynomial with the order higher than 4). But when I feed an identical expression to `Solve`, it finds the roots:

```
Solve[9 g^8 - 9 b^2 g^8 - b^(2/3) g^4 (10 + 16 g^6 + g^12) + b^(4/3) (1 + 2 g^6 (8 + 5 g^6)) == 0, g]
```

(Output: analytical roots.)

To make sure the expressions are identical:

```
FullSimplify[9 g^8 - 9 b^2 g^8 - b^(2/3) g^4 (10 + 16 g^6 + g^12) + b^(4/3) (1 + 2 g^6 (8 + 5 g^6)) == -(-b^(2/3) + g^4) (b^(2/3) - 9 g^4 + 16 b^(2/3) g^6 - 9 b^(4/3) g^8 + b^(2/3) g^12)]
(* Out[]= True *)
```

Is it just a matter of luck, or are there certain conditions, under which `Solve` works better?

Comment: What's better? Both are analytical. I personally prefer the more compact and numerically stable space-age solution over the complicated bronze-age solution.

Comment: `Solve[(-(-b^(2/3) + g^4) (b^(2/3) - 9 g^4 + 16 b^(2/3) g^6 - 
       9 b^(4/3) g^8 + b^(2/3) g^12) // Expand) == 0, g] `  does what you want.

Comment: Akku14, thanks. I don't know the reason why Solve works better with an expanded expression, but I'll take it into consideration. John Doty, the bronze-age solutions are usually faster than numerical.

Comment: I'm not talking about numerical solutions, but numerical **evaluation** of the analytical solutions is an issue. Simple `Root` expressions behave better than complicated radical expressions.

Comment: What is also interesting is that while Akku14's expression does yield the analytical-expression roots, the reduced expression Solve[b^(2/3) - 9 g^4 + 16 b^(2/3) g^6 - 9 b^(4/3) g^8 + b^(2/3) g^12 == 0, g] (without the factor -b^(2/3) + g^4, which just gives the two roots ±b^(1/6)) does not, with or without Expand, while it would seem like a simpler, lower-order expression should get resolved more easily.

Comment: And, playing around, the radical expression is very badly behaved in this case. Try a `/.b->1.` substitution for both expressions.

Comment: John Doty, the case b = 1 is a degenerate case, so I am interested only in b > 1 cases. Anyway, the radical solution g = Sqrt[b^(1/3) + (b - 1)^(1/3)/b^(1/6) ((Sqrt[b] + 1)^(1/3) + (Sqrt[b] - 1)^(1/3))] seems to behave quite well even for b -> 1.

Comment: Of the 16 radical solutions of your original problem, only 4 are clean with `b->1.`. Six have either imaginary or real parasitics, and another 6 are `Indeterminate`. All of the `Root` solutions are clean. This kind of behavior is one of the reasons I prefer `Root` objects.